# Python based colored logging in github runner with ubuntu-latest

Tags: python, github-actions, python-logging

I am using this library in python using this library https://coloredlogs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

```
import coloredlogs, logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG', logger=logger)
logger.debug("test")
```

The above code works as expected on my local and `test` is printed out in `green.`
However, when I run this on a github runner like this

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Create workflow
      run: |
        python scripts/my-logging-file.py
```

The generated output on the runner doesn't have any color. Is there any specific env. variable that needs to set or any other change?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to `coloredlogs==12.0` works around the issue described below as per [kosta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3288346/kosta)'s comment.

---

`coloredlogs` uses auto detection by default, which, on linux, only enables colored output iff the output is a TTY. According to the documentation it should work to pass `isatty = True` via `**kw` to `coloredlogs.install` to force colored output.

But documentation and code are inconsistent, it looks like the code has a bug and forcing colored output doesn't work. See https://github.com/xolox/python-coloredlogs/issues/84.

```py
import coloredlogs, logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG', logger=logger, isatty=true)
logger.debug("test")
```

> **`coloredlogs.install(level=None, **kw)`**
> `isatty` – `True` to use a `ColoredFormatter`, `False` to use a normal `Formatter` (defaults to auto-detection using `terminal_supports_colors()`).

https://coloredlogs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=isatty#coloredlogs.install

`terminal_supports_colors` is from `humanfriendly` and returns true iff the passed stream is a TTY. In a GitHub Actions runner the output is redirected.

> **`humanfriendly.terminal.terminal_supports_colors(stream=None)`**
> Check if a stream is connected to a terminal that supports ANSI escape sequences.
> Parameters: stream – The stream to check (a file-like object, defaults to `sys.stdout`).
> Returns:    `True` if the terminal supports ANSI escape sequences, False otherwise.

https://humanfriendly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#humanfriendly.terminal.terminal_supports_colors

**Source code**

[https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly/blob/05d02d4f6ef317edf97aca679411ec6514685243/humanfriendly/terminal/**init**.py#L702](https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly/blob/05d02d4f6ef317edf97aca679411ec6514685243/humanfriendly/terminal/__init__.py#L702)

[https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly/blob/05d02d4f6ef317edf97aca679411ec6514685243/humanfriendly/terminal/**init**.py#L402](https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly/blob/05d02d4f6ef317edf97aca679411ec6514685243/humanfriendly/terminal/__init__.py#L402)

Comment: Thanks, `humanfriendly.terminal.terminal_supports_colors` actually returns `False` on the github runner (`ubuntu-latest`). Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: `isatty=True` didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Documentation and code are inconsistent, apparently there's no way to force it. See https://github.com/xolox/python-coloredlogs/issues/84.

Comment: Downgrading the version `coloredlogs==12.0` seems to work for now